# Why does Mac running Ventura OS now insist on using FN key to deliver function keys

Tags: macos

For some reason, the latest Mac OS - unprompted - insists that I press the FN key for the functionality that is displayed on functions. Why? And how do I change back permanently?

Comment: Fine by me. I've asked on the relevant exchange. Your comment didn't provide a solution, though. Oh well. At least you responded :)

Answer (score 1):

You can change these settings if you go to System preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard shortcuts > Function Keys.

You should then see the same thing as in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of macOS Ventura function key settings]